Jasmine angular testing async promise
I need test an asyncronus promise in Jasmin and I don't know how to do it becase angular return an error every time.
myService.ts
async getNewContext(): Promise<IContext> {
    const test1 = await this.service1.function();
    const test2 = await this.service2.function();
    const test3 = await this.service3.function();
    const test4 = await this.service4.function();

    const cc = {
      .
      .
      .
    };

    this.setContext = cc;

    return cc;
  }

component.ts
setFeatures() {
    this.myService.getNewContext().then((response) => {});
}

component.spect.ts
.
.
.
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [...],
      imports: [...],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: myService,
          useValue: {
            select: () => [],
            getNewContext: () => [],
          },
        }
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

I am getting an error saying "getNewContext is not a function". Any idea please?

Make the function return a promise, then exists only when a promise is returned.
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [...],
      imports: [...],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: myService,
          useValue: {
            select: () => [],
            getNewContext: () => Promise.resolve(1),
          },
        }
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));


It worked like a charm. Thank you very much!!!
